# Is it 'in an age' or 'in ages'?

Tags: grammar

For example 'I haven't done X in an age' vs 'I haven't done X in ages'. Which is correct? Or is it simply a case of American English vs British English?

Comment: "I haven't done X in ages" is (much) more idiomatic in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks As it is in Britain. "In an age" is far less common, but idiomatic nonetheless.

Comment: Both are grammatical, one is more common than the other, and the Atlantic Ocean and the Irish Republic have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plural form is the more common, the singular one is idiomatic in BrE.

***[Ages (plural)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/age_1#age_1__4)***, (also an age [singular]) (informal, especially British English):

> - a very long time:
>
>   - *I waited for ages.
>       It'll probably take ages to find a parking space.
>       Carlos left ages ago.
>       It's been an age since we've seen them.*

OLD